# We're sometimes obtuse, we're sometimes right

Tags: riddle, word

> We're sometimes obtuse, we're sometimes right.
> We have eight sides, and proffer insight.
> Columbus likes our shape, seers like our font.
> As do mages, pirates, and debutantes.

Who are we?  Three words.

Comment: Why is it being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> magic 8 ball

We're sometimes obtuse,

> They can provide seemingly meaningless answers like "Try Again Later"

we're sometimes right.

> Given that they often have yes/no responses, given enough questions and responses, then they will be right on occasion

We have eight sides,

> Not really sure about this once since they allegedly have 20 sides, maybe to do with the 8?

and proffer insight.

> You ask them questions and they provide responses

Columbus likes our shape,

> Spherical, like the Earth that he sailed around

seers like our font.

> Magic 8 balls are used for divination

As do mages,

> Magic

pirates,

> Pieces of 8

and debutantes.

> Ball

Comment: Well done.  The "eight sides" was kind of a dad joke, rot13(urer "rvtug" vf na nqwrpgvir).  The "font" refers to rot13(obgu gur jngre erprcgnpyr naq nf n pbzzba zvffcryyvat bs sbhag).  And with "Columbus", I was going for rot13(Pbyhzohf rtt, fvapr vg unf n syng fvqr).

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of rot13(Pbyhzohf rtt, fvapr vg unf n syng fvqr) before, so learnt something new today!